# Unable to connect to the electron / CEF app using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, electron, desktop-application

I am trying to automate [electron-api-demos][1]app using this sample code.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int port = 9223;// Open App

          Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
          "C:\\Program Files\\Sample.exe"
          , null, new
          File("C:\\Program Files\\Sample"
          ));

         ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        String remoteDebuggingAddress = "localhost:" + port;
        options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", remoteDebuggingAddress);
        options.addArguments("remote-debugging-port=9223");

        // options.addArguments("electron-port="+port);
        options.setBinary(
                "C:\\Program Files\\Sample.exe");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\narays24\\eclipse-workspace\\xyz\\src\\demo1\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        String location = "C:\\Users\\narays24\\eclipse-workspace\\xyz\\src\\demo1";
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String time = dateFormat.format(now);
        File dir = new File(location + time);

        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("directory already exists");
            //Do nothing
        }

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(location + time + "\\screen1.png"));
            }
        catch (IOException e)
             {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());

             }

    }
```

I am able to access the app and get a screenshot.
I am not able to access the cef through the below port :

> http://localhost:9223/

I am getting the following at the localhost , but not the elements :

> Inspectable WebContents scannerui/appfiles/index.html

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong.
After changing the selenium to alpha , I am able to run this with out errors .

**Updated edit :**

I am able to navigate to google and automate in cef . But I am not able to control or perform any actions on application's menu bar or buttons or text boxes.

My cef is based on chrome 57 .so I downgraded the chrome browser to 57 , chrome driver to 2.26 and selenium Java libraries to 2.36 .

Still I am not able to click on desktop application specific buttons or text boxes. But am able to driver.navigate to google and perform tests.

Can anyone help here? I am using Java , selenium

I also tried on electron application as mentioned above, still no luck

Comment: I will have a fresh look at your issue first hour tomorrow. However I can see you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) v _4.0.0-alpha-3_ which is a _Alpha_ release. We are still working for a _Beta_ release, the last stable release being _Selenium_ v _3.141.159_ and last stable major release being _Selenium_ v _3.14.0_

Comment: Ok I will check with the stable version and update

Comment: There is a distinct issue in all of the 3 code block as per the error stack traces. Can you please [edit the question](/posts/62372230/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I will edit the question content to one problem

Comment: @DebanjanB, I have edited the question

Comment: I see that my CEF application crome version is 57 and I am using the current verion of chrome driver and chrome and chromium browsers , Will that an issue why I am not able to get the application in debug mode?

Comment: Of coarse that would result into a binary version mismatch issue.

Answer (score 1):

@DebanjanB,
Thanks for the help.
After I changed the version of the selenium to alpha , I am able to connect to the app with out errors.
I am using the following code now :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int port = 9223;
        // Open App

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "C:\\Program Files\\SampleApp.exe", null,
                new File("C:\\Program Files\\SampleApp"));

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        String remoteDebuggingAddress = "localhost:" + port;
        options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", remoteDebuggingAddress);
        options.addArguments("remote-debugging-port=9223");
        options.setBinary(
                "C:\\Program Files\\SampleApp.exe");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\xyz\\eclipse-workspace\\xyz\\src\\demo1\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }
```

The issue is I am not able to access the elements in chromium at http://localhost:9223/
When I open the chromium or chrome browser at teh local host the following text is displayed . 
Normally a link is expected . Link or the WebElements are not displayed.

> Inspectable WebContents  scannerui/appfiles/index.html

Answer (score 0):

check your code again, its pop up error of missing library. check if any resource if missing on directory,

check your Java annotation if they are missing in your code and Focus on this line

Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-3', revision: '8c567de6dc' System info: host: 'INDMRZBK5X95V6G', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver at